# Reverse string in PAWN language

Tags: string, reverse, string-concatenation, pawn

I try to reverse word but stack in some problem which I can’t explain and don’t know what to do.

```
new word{8};
GetWord(coords, word);
printf ("%s\n", word);
new doubleWord {16};
new reversedWord {16};
strcat (doubleWord, word, 16);
printf ("doubleword = %s\n", doubleWord);
strcat (doubleWord, word, 16);
printf ("doubleword = %s\n", doubleWord);
ReverseWord(doubleWord, reversedWord);
strcat (reversedWord, reversedWord, 16);
printf ("doubleword = %s, length = %d\n", doubleWord, strlen(doubleWord));
printf ("doubleword = %s, reverseword = %s\n", doubleWord, reversedWord);
```

My reverse function:

```
ReverseWord(word{}, rev{}) {
    for (new i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        rev{i} = word{8-i};
    }
}
```

In function I reverse only one part because `doubleWord` is just cope of word and doesn’t matter which part to reverse. Then I concatenate it and after that value of `doubleWord` just vanish. I don’t know how to explaine this and don’t find explanation in PAWN guide.
Here screenshot with results.
[image: first_reverse_test]

I try to reverse whole word of course. Like this:

```
ReverseWord(word{}, rev{}) {
    for (new i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        rev{i} = word{15-i};
    }
}
```

And delete `strcat`:

```
printf ("doubleword = %s\n", doubleWord);
ReverseWord(doubleWord, reversedWord);
printf ("doubleword = %s, length = %d\n", doubleWord, strlen(doubleWord));
```

But then I come to `reversedWord` get `doubleWord` value in the end of it.
Here screenshot with results.
[image: second_reverse_test]

In second version I also try `strdel` to delete `doubleWord` value from the end:

```
printf ("doubleword = %s\n", doubleWord);
ReverseWord(doubleWord, reversedWord);
strdel(reversedWord,16,32);
printf ("doubleword = %s, length = %d\n", doubleWord, strlen(doubleWord));
```

but I get `doubleWord` modified again!. Here screenshot with results.
[image: third_reverse_test]

Who can explane what happen? Does PAWN remember value of variable in heap or stack and get the last used variable? And how can I reverse word cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. First, you reserve 8 characters for the initial string, but the null terminating character is missing. If you want the strings to have 8 or 16 characters, the sizes should be 9 and 17.

The second issue is that you are passing the length of the array in characters to `strcat`, but the function expects the size in cells. Combined with the fact the the strings do not fit in their target arrays, the function writes the null byte to a wrong place. This is the next array on the stack, leading to both `doubleWord` and `word` being "erased" (the first cell set to 0).

Simply remove `16` from the arguments, since it should be filled automatically anyway. It it doesn't, use `sizeof(doubleWord)`.